# Angular how to get XSRF-TOKEN cookie

Tags: angular, spring, cookies, csrf, interceptor

Hi i want to add CSRF protection to my app

I have an angular app in front and spring in backend

In backend i have this configuration

```
  .csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(getCsrfTokenRepository()))

    private CsrfTokenRepository getCsrfTokenRepository() {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        tokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
        return tokenRepository;
    }
```

In angular i have this interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpXsrfTokenExtractor,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Injectable()
export class XsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  #headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
  constructor(private tokenService: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor, private cookieService: CookieService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const token = this.tokenService.getToken(); <-- token is null

    // Be careful not to overwrite an existing header of the same name.
    if (token !== null && !request.headers.has(this.#headerName)) {
      request = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set(this.#headerName, token),
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

[image: token cookie]

In Chrome i have a XSRF-TOKEN so my problem is when i´m trying to get the token value, the function this.tokenService.getToken(); is always null, so i dont know what to do to get the XSRF Cookie value